# serializing and deserializing .net 4.0 ExpandoObject

Tags: json, .net-4.0, json.net

I get the error:

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' to type 'System.Collections.IDictionary'.

Normally, I'd derive `ExpandoObject` and then put an attribute on the derived class to indicate the custom TypeConverter that I write.  I don't know how else to register a TypeConverter for a type.  ExpandoObject is sealed though.

The one thread on the codeplex project had a patch to the distribution.  I'd rather maybe derive from JsonConverter, although, i haven't done that yet.

So before I go off in a direction, is there a suggested approach here?

Comment: What kind of serializer are you trying to use?

Comment: I am using the Newtonsoft Json serializer.

Answer (score 1):

[`ExpandoObjectConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_ExpandoObjectConverter.htm) was added to Json.NET (formerly Newtonsoft) in what appears to be March 2011.